# How to draw arabic or hebrew text along a path java2d

Tags: java

has someone an example of how to drawing arabic or hebrew text along a path in  java2d? 
I look this example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawtextalongacurve.htm but when i try it with arabic or hebrew text it don't work. I have a mirror effect.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't use java2d, but I only have checked the docs and noticed [Section 4.3.2 Ordering Text](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/904preview/jdk14doc/docs/guide/2d/spec/j2d-fonts.fm3.html) What you can do is to modify the positions of the characters when using _right-to-left_ languages. (Better read the whole page)

Comment: When i modify the position of the characters i have the characters in right order but i obtain characters without liguature

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your Java code is saved in UTF-8
[image]

Then one simple solution is to reverse the text like this:

```
String s = (new StringBuffer("מה הבעיה אחי?")).reverse().toString();
```

But this will cause issues with special characters ( **like (,{,>** )

The correct way is to use layoutGlyphVector method
giving it Font.LAYOUT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT flag:

```
GlyphVector gv = font.layoutGlyphVector(g2.getFontRenderContext(), s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length(), Font.LAYOUT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Instead of

```
 GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, s,);
```

Then your text will layout correctly:

[image: Full working code:]

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RollingText extends JPanel {
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    String s = "מה הבעיה אחי?";
    Font font = new Font("LucidaSans", Font.PLAIN, 24);
    FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
    g2.translate(40, 80);

    GlyphVector gv = font.layoutGlyphVector(g2.getFontRenderContext(), s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length(), Font.LAYOUT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

    int length = gv.getNumGlyphs();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      Point2D p = gv.getGlyphPosition(i);
      double theta = (double) i / (double) (length - 1) * Math.PI / 4;
      AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(p.getX(), p.getY());
      at.rotate(theta);
      Shape glyph = gv.getGlyphOutline(i);
      Shape transformedGlyph = at.createTransformedShape(glyph);
      g2.fill(transformedGlyph);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("RollingText v1.0");
    f.getContentPane().add(new RollingText());
    f.setSize(600, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```